# Static classes in Java--something is being shadowed

Tags: java

Following is the simplest example of **static inner class** in Java. Let's look at it.

```
package staticclass;

final class Outer
{
    final public static class Inner
    {
        static String s = "Black";
    }

    static Extra Inner = new Extra();   //The inner class name and the object name of the class  Extra are same and it is responsible for shadowing/hiding Inner.s
}

final class Extra
{
    String s = "White";
}

final public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(Outer.Inner.s);
    }
}
```

---

Within the **Outer** class, there is a static class named **Inner** and a static object with the same name **Inner** of type Extra. The program displays **Whilte** on the console, a string in the **Extra** class through **Outer.Inner.s** in main() which is intended to display the string contained in the **Inner** class within the **Outer** class

---

Why is there no name collision between a static inner class and a static object of type Extra? How does the **Extra** class enjoys the higher priority than the **Inner** class and displays the string contained in the **Extra** class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what the JLS says. which I believe applies to your case:

> 6.3.2 Obscured Declarations
>
> A simple name may occur in contexts where it may potentially be
>   interpreted as the name of a variable, a type or a package. In these
>   situations, the rules of §6.5 specify that a variable will be chosen
>   in preference to a type, and that a type will be chosen in preference
>   to a package.

So since your `static Extra Inner = new Extra()` is a variable, it will be chosen over `final public static class Inner` which is a type.

The quite more elaborate paragraph [6.3.1](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/names.html#6.3.1) specifies how shadowing generally is to be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Because the inner class actual type name is Outer$Inner.  It's a convenience that you can reference it as Inner.  I imagine the compiler knows this and takes the more explicit rule for the local variable.