# How to access a member of a nested class, that is hidden by a member of the outer class

Tags: java, inner-classes, ambiguous

I have a source-code generator that risks generating the following type of code (just an example):

```
public class Outer {
    public static final Object Inner = new Object();

    public static class Inner {
        public static final Object Help = new Object();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Outer.Inner.Help);
        //                             ^^^^ Cannot access Help
    }
}
```

In the above example, `Inner` is ambiguously defined inside of `Outer`. `Outer.Inner` can be both a nested class, and a static member. It seems as though both `javac` and Eclipse compilers cannot dereference `Outer.Inner.Help`. How can I access `Help`?

Remember, the above code is generated, so renaming things is not a (simple) option.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8130060/static-classes-in-java-something-is-being-shadowed

Comment: Are you sure that this doesn't work as-is?  It looks like what I'd expect to work.

Comment: It's a very lucky circumstance that you got it to work at all. You are basically accessing the static field by qualifying it with an instance of that type. This is why we have Java naming conventions, to prevent such clashes.

Comment: "ambiguous" how? `Inner` is **not** an inner class, by definition, because it's static.

Comment: @goldilocks So it's a nested class. It doesn't change the point.

Comment: @LukasEder, Your workaround doesn't seem to work for me. I get a class cast exception.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: okay, but then the distinction "both an inner class and a static member" 1) does not make sense, 2) is false.  Member `Inner` is just an object.

Comment: @aioobe I'm testing in Eclipse Helios, Java 6, works for me.

Comment: @goldilocks OP has a naming clash problem. It's a real problem. Maybe his wording isn't JLS-perfect, but the problem is clear.

Comment: I personally would do one of three things: (1) rule illegal any input that results in this code; (2) adopt a name mangling scheme so that the two things always end up having different names; (3) ensure that `Inner` (the variable) is always of type `Inner` (the class).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: I agree 100%, I just wanted to point the language problem out, because they often indicate a misconception.  I'd say the clash is not a matter of "ambiguity" it is just a mistake, period.

Comment: @LouisWasserman: Yes, I'm sure

Comment: @goldilocks: I changed the wording from "inner" to "nested"

Comment: @aix (and others): Yes, I'd prefer to rename things. But let's assume renaming is not an option (as this is about generated code)

Comment: But do you control the generation of the code? If yes, then aix's approach is valid. Especially because Java is unescapably vulnerable to naming clashes.

Comment: @LukasEder: It's your question, so you are of course free to rule things out. :-) However, I don't understand what's so hard (or undesirable) about an automatic name mangling scheme.

Comment: Ie, you have a generator that generates "worst practice" -> "invalid" code?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, what have I misunderstood? ([link](http://ideone.com/fNGPx)).

Comment: @aioobe Ha ha, cool, you actually **ran** it! Yes, that settles the misunderstanding -- when I said "works" I only meant "compiles" :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik (and others): Yes I control the generation of the code. I want to figure out whether this is really "worst practice" in case of which I'll find a mangling scheme. The collision will be quite rare. But before I think about that, I want to understand that aspect of the Java language

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following works for me (with a warning about accessing static members in a non-static way):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(((Inner)null).Help);
}
```

Comment: +1. Nice. @SuppressWarnings("static-access") to suppress the warning.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(new Inner().Help);
}
```

Comment: That would work, yes. But I don't want to instanciate `Inner` in order to access a static member of it

Comment: I appreciate that it looks unclean, but it is about a simple code as you are going to get, given the ambiguity.  I doubt the cost of the instantiation would be much.

Comment: OK, I agree. As a workaround, it would be OK. Although I'd still prefer the casting (if that is a formally correct solution)